# Add the custom analyzer universally to all the fields in Nest Elastic search 6.2

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an elastic search index that has more than 100 properties. I want to add the custom analyzer for most of the fields. I want to avoid typical nest syntax to specify the analyzer per field.
[writing Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html)

Let me know if there is any other alternative to set the analyzer as a universal setting.
Please let me know your thoughts on the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use dynamic template to specify which analyzer you want for your fields. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

You can [change the default analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) for all `text` fields within an index by adding an analyzer with the name `"default"` to the index settings *when creating the index*

```cs
var defaultIndex = "my_index";
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(an => an
                .Standard("default", st => st
                    .StopWords("_english_")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which will send a create index request with the following body

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "standard",
          "stopwords": [
            "_english_"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you wanted this to apply to all indices created, you can use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to apply this convention to all automatically created indices

```cs
var putIndexTemplateResponse = client.PutIndexTemplate("default_analyzer", t => t
    .IndexPatterns("*")
    .Order(0)
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(an => an
                .Standard("default", st => st
                    .StopWords("_english_")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```